# Overriding pre/post execute in AsyncTask and calling super.onPre/PostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Is it mandatory to call super.onPreExecute when overriding onPreExecute in an AsyncTask?
What does AsyncTask.onPreExecute and other methods actually do?
Same question for onPostExecute and onCancelled

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
{

@Override
protected void onCancelled(Boolean result) {

    super.onCancelled(result);   //<-DO I HAVE TO?

            //My onCancelled code below


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);  //<-DO I HAVE TO?

            //My onPostExecute code below
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();  //<-DO I HAVE TO?

            //My onPreExecute code below

}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `super`. Here's the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java).

As you can see, the default implementation does nothing.

```
/**
* Runs on the UI thread before {@link #doInBackground}.
*
* @see #onPostExecute
* @see #doInBackground
*/
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

/**
* <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
* specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.</p>
*
* <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
*
* @param result The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
*
* @see #onPreExecute
* @see #doInBackground
* @see #onCancelled(Object)
*/
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good practice to still call `super` because of future updates to `AsyncTask`? There is nothing there now, but what if they change it...

Answer (score 1):

No we don't compulsorily need to Override the methods
 **onPreExecute & onPostExecute.**

**onPreExecute**
called before the **doInbackground** Process starts We can add code in this method which we have to do before any thing Start working **doInbackground**.

**doInbackground**
works in background so in this method do whatever we want to do in background like calling web service and all. but **CAUTION** for this method is not to set the UI widgets in This method . If set it will give Exception.

**onPostExecute**
called after the completion on **doInbackground** & in this method we are able to set the UI widgets and other code to set after the Webservice call completed.

**OnCancelled**
A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to **isCancelled()** to return true.

check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) link.
Hope this help you.

Comment: I was asking about the implementation of the base class, but thank you anyway for your time.